# In a for loop, how do I increment a counter once every other time?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, increment

I apologize for the clunky wording of the question. English is not my first language.

I am creating a scrollable list. Each element of this list consists of a column with two rows. I don't want to offset the column until each row is filled. I basically only want to increment the offset counter every two cycles of the for loop. My code for this is as follows:

```
var j = 0;
for(var i=0;i<localArray.length;i++){
    var iconLeft = 145 * j;

    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.id              = "page_icon_" + i;
    div.style.position  = "absolute";
    div.style.height    = "45px";
    div.style.width     = "145px";
    div.style.left      = iconLeft + "px";

    var item = fishListItem(localArray[i].info);
    div.appendChild(item);
    var parent = document.getElementById('tut_icons_scroll');

    if(i%2){
        item.style.top = "40px";
        parent.appendChild(div);
    }else{          
        parent.appendChild(div);
    }
    if (i%2) {
        j++;
    }
```

Is there a way to do with without introducing the variable 'j'?

Comment: It's not clear why you need `j` here at all. Why not just use `i%2` like you're already doing?

Comment: Yes, the last 3 lines were unnecessary, but i%2 will always give me 0 or 1 for any positive integer.

Comment: Well, yea, that's the point. If you're tracking the cumulative number of cells in a table that is of X cells and Y columns, inside of a single loop, then the offset of Y can easily become `X % Y`where in your case `Y = 2` so the offset is either 0 or 1. -- Sorry edit

Comment: I think you misunderstand what I'm asking. The offset increases by 1 for every 2 loop iterations. I actually found that using i%2 was unecessary because I could use css to track evens and odds. If we look at a sequence, i is 1,2,3,4,5,6....n whereas j would be 0,0,1,1,2,2...n. I will definitely have more than 2 columns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just do:

```
Math.floor(i/2)
```

in place of j.

Answer (score 2):

In this case, you can replace all instances of `j` with `Math.floor(i/2)`.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to use pure css `nth-child` to accomplish this requirement

```
if(i%2){
    item.style.top = "40px";
    parent.appendChild(div);
}
```

to replace this, in your css `div:nth-child(even) { top: 40px; }`

to replace j, just create a class for the column, set the margin for it, and position set to relative, float set to left.

can you provide your code in `jsbin` or `jsfiddler` so I can help you out. I thought this solution is much clear and easy to maintain.

Comment: Hmmm, this is an interesting solution. I'll have to try it out!

Comment: share a jsfiddler, let's try it out

Answer (score 0):

Would it be easy to use a pass element i and then (i+1) to a function and then count up by 2s?

Something like:

```
function appendFunction(elementToAdd, addItTo) {}

for (var i = 0; i < localArray.length; i+=2) { 
  var iconLeft = 145*(i%2); // at 0 
  var iconRight = 145*(i%2 + 1); // at 145
  appendFunction(elementToAdd[i], addItTo}
  appendFunction(elementToAdd[i+1], addItTo}
}
```

Not sure if the function helps a lot, but anyways, adding by twos and treating the cases of (x) and (x+1) within the for loop should allow you to increment a counter once every other time. You have to say what to happen twice each time, but one you make a function for it, it's about as long and leaves you with an easily reusable bit to append the elements in the way to place the text.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Math.floor as stated in a couple of answers.  Or bit-shift right by one:

```
i>>1;
```

Either substitute `j` with this expression, or use: `var j=i>>1;`.  `i>>1` will have the following values for each loop with an incrementing `i`:

```
0,0,1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,...
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
for(var i=0, j=0; i < 10; i++%2 && ++j) {
  console.log(i,j);
}
```

Comment: @KickButtowski please read the question again - It is specifically about incrementing a counter every other iteration